# Use of code coverage tool 'coverage.py' to test code coverage having multiple child subprocess shell command calls

Tags: python, subprocess, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm using coverage.py tool https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html to see code coverage of tests around a python project.

I have 8 tests which may cover different files of the project , Each of this test invokes another python script using `subprocess.call(["python", "project.py"])`  as a part of the test.
I am able to get coverage report of individual test by specifying `subprocess.call(["coverage", "project.py"])` i.e by specifying "coverage" in the command line at the place where individual test is invoked but I'm not able to get a consolidated report of all the tests.

The idea is each individual test may cover only 16% of code but different tests may cover different parts of the code and may cover around 90% overall , currently as I'm able to see individual reports, they all show 16% coverage only.

Is there any way that I can get a consolidated report of all 8 tests which are run in a for loop one after the other invoking subprocess.call()
I have referred to https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/subprocess.html but couldn't get a working solution from there. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cmd.html#combining-data-files-coverage-combine

Did you look at this?

Comment: Please provide a sample, minimal program so that people can try it

Comment: `for test_script in tests:
     subprocess.call(['python',test_script])`

There are 8 test scripts , each test script runs
`subprocess.call(['coverage','run','project.py','cmd_args'])
subprocess.call(["coverage","html","-d",cov_report_path])`

This gives individual test report as html in the given path , I'm looking for a way to have consolidated report i.e coverage should combine the data of all these tests (or) coverage should run continously on each of these subprocesses without ending after each individual subprocess

Comment: Thanks @whiplash , Your suggestion really helped .
I am able to run individual tests , save their data at one place and finally combine them.
However when I run any other python file a .coverage.some_unique_number file is created in that directory which is similar to data file of coverage for each test.
In this process as `subprocess.call()` is involved , I had to set environment variable `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` ,I suspect this as the reason for it , any suggestions as to why this file is getting created even though I run different python file.

Comment: Are you saying you ran `python someOtherFile.py` and that is also generating a .coverage file?

Comment: Yes exactly , any suggestion on this

Comment: did you try unsetting the env variable running the code?

Comment: Yes I tried setting the env variable just for the test and  unsetting the env variable after it and it helped. Thank you @whiplash your inputs helped me. Sorry I forgot to reply to your comment earlier